# How to use Leaflet with Proj4.js when GeoServer is serving tiles in EPSG:404000?

Tags: geoserver, leaflet, wms, cartesian, epsg-40400

I have a GeoTIFF served via a **GeoServer** WMS service and referenced in the **EPSG:404000** CRS (Wildcard 2D cartesian plane in metric unit).

I would like to display the tiles in my **Leaflet** client and keep its original Cartesian coordinates.

I know that I need to use the [Proj4Leaflet](https://github.com/kartena/Proj4Leaflet) plugin to use system that are not natively supported by Leaflet.

But the problem is that [EPSG:404000](https://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/epsg404000/) seems to have no Proj4 definition.

How can I specify Proj4Leaflet to use this spatial reference?

Comment: `But the problem is that EPSG:404000 seems to have no Proj4 definition.` That's correct, it has no definition, see the https://gis.stackexchange.com/tags/epsg-40400/info wiki for info.  If it's your geoserver service you should configure the native projection for the GeoTIFF

Comment: 404000 is a sure sign something is wrong with your data source.

Comment: It is 404000 since my Geotiff is made of non geographical coordinates that represent indoor objects. So I don't specify any CRS when I build my raster with PDAL. But is there a CRS (Proj4 supported) that handle a metric cartesian representation which I can use to build my raster?

Comment: For cartesian coordinates you do not need Proj4, Leaflet has built in CRS for that: `L.CRS.Simple`.

Comment: Yes that's what I figured out but you need to extend L.CRS.Simple in order to have Leaflet calling GeoServer with the good CRS label: const EPSG404000 = L.Util.extend({}, L.CRS.Simple, {code: 'EPSG:404000',});